# Django eCommerce advice

Tags: python, django

I am reading 'Beginning Django eCommerce' by Jim McGaw and I am trying to add a feature that allows customers shopping for smartphone to pick a memory card with it or not. This is what I did:

1. I created a model for the Memory card
2. I added this to my add to cart form

   ```
   mem_8 = MemoryCard.objects.get(name='eight')         
   mem_16 = MemoryCard.objects.get(name='sixteen')    
   mem_32 = MemoryCard.objects.get(name='thirtytwo')
   choices = (
       ('without', 'Without Memory Card'),
       (mem_8, '8GB + 20$'),
       (mem_16, '16GB + 25$'),
       (mem_32, '32GB + 30$')
       )

    memory_card = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=choices, attrs = {'class':'choices'}))
   ```

At this point i get an Integrity error that says that the memory_card_id is null and it cannot be null

My question is do I continue what i started(if so any suggestions on the error would be nice) or there is much more simple and easy way to do it?

Comment: This isn't a question about e-commerce at all, please pick a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not the way it works. You can't use a model object as the ID property in a select widget. And you definitely shouldn't be doing `get`s inside the form declaration.

Instead you should use a ModelChoiceField, with the queryset pointing to the MemoryCard model:

```
memory_card = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MemoryCard.objects.all())
```

if you have more memory card options that you don't want to show here, you could narrow it down:

```
memory_card = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MemoryCard.objects.filter(name__in=['eight', 'sixteen', 'thirtytwo'])
```

Comment: Can you please explain why its not a good idea to do 'get' inside a form declaration and isn't this queryset=MemoryCard.objects.all() a get inside the form?

Comment: No, because `get` is not lazy but `all` (and `filter`) are. So the get would be executed at import time, rather than at the time the form is actually used.

Comment: One last thing! In case the user chooses not to take a memory_card, but the cart item model requires one should i create another model object with price 0.00?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm considering using Django for a bespoke ecommerce site.  Do you think it is a good option or should I be considering other options such as Magento?